# Finding the minimum number of parent nodes that summarize the graph

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, terminology

So I ran into this graph engineering problem which I can't even google because I don't know a proper name for it, I'm sure (hope ?) it does have a name in Graph Theory.

So I have a graph **G** in which every node is a parent and child at the same time. Regardless of the type of relation (parenthood or childood) every node can have between at least one relation to another node up till 18 relations with different nodes.

Here what complicates life for me: every two nodes that are related are parent and child to each other at the same time, depending on which one we take first, the other will be child to it and vice versa. The task is to find the set of minimum parent nodes that will summarize the graph. For example, the node **n[5]** has lets say **18** childs, so in the minimized graph we take this one and delete all other 18 and repeat this process through the entire graph until all nodes are replaced by a parent.

My solution was to order the nodes according to their number of childs and start deleting on that order. At the end of this process I suspect some nodes will remain without any parent in which case I just add them to the minimized graph. While this works, it doesn't necessarilly give an optimal solution because sometimes I delete a node listed as child but it is also a parent to alot of other child nodes. There is maybe more interest in  keeping it and delete all of its children instead. In Addition of course to the number of remaining parent-less nodes, obviously the less the better.

I was wondering if there is a name to this and if there is a way to find an optimal solution without having to find it using shear bruit force

Thanks

Comment: Just edited the OP

Comment: You seem to be looking for a [dominating set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set) of the graph, with the added restriction that no two vertices of the dominating set are adjacent (i.e. they form an independent set of vertices).

Comment: @JaapScherphuis that seems to be it , NP-complete .. of course